# Distinct Random select

Tags: sql-server, random

Hi can anyone help with this little MS SQL Puzzle.

I basically need to get a 1 random answer from each of the submitters.

```
id,   submitter,   answer

1,    James,        Blue

2,    James,        Red

3,    James,        Orange

4,    Ian,        Yellow

5,    Ian,        Pink

6,    Robert,       Red
```

I have tried the following but obviously this will always get the min(id) or Max(id)  what I need is a random(id)?

```
select * from #tmpData 
 where id in (
  select min(id ) FROM #tmpData 
   group by submitter
            )
```

Thanks in advance..

Comment: I edited your tags. I assume you are working with SQL-Server. In your future questions, please provide the DBMS you are dealing with (and "MS SQL" is not quite descriptive. MS is a company and SQL is a language. MS has several dbms: SQL-Server, Access, etc...) It's also good if you add the version you are using (i.e. 2005, 2008, 2008R2, 2012, ...)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming a not very old version of SQL-Server, you can use `ROW_NUMBER()` to find one row per `submitter`:

```
; with r as
  ( select id, submitter, answer, 
           rnd = row_number() over (partition by submitter order by newid())
    from #tmpData 
  )
select id, submitter, answer
from r
where rnd = 1 ;
```

Test at: [SQLfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/81ceb/1)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM #tmpData
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

This should work. Let me know if there are further questions!

Comment: No this would only select one random answer,  I need 1 answer from each of the submitters.      eg id's 2,5,6   or 1,4,6 or 3,5,6